# Arabic letters in php file changed to symbols

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I was using Arabic language in my PHP file (`info.php`) normal for long time But when I changed `functions.php` file from ANSI to UTF-8 encoding, then all my page `info.php` become strange characters. I downloaded the file `info.php` by FileZilla to see what encoding has, and the surprise is I found the whole file characters are also symbols and the encoding is UTF-8 Normal.

My database is utb8-general-ci.

Editor: UTF-8.

I'm using meta tag with UTF-8.

MySQL connect also UTF-8.

I have tried to change back `functions.php` to ANSI but the symbols didn't come back to Arabic.

What should I do please I have my site online. Thanks.

Comment: The characters were correct when the DB was `ansi`? You can't get back misencoded data. It is like watching a tv show filmed in black and white on a color tv, there no reference of the original colors.

Comment: @chris85 i know , i said my file was rewrited automatic in symboles it self . i dont mean its arabic in file and it how symbols , no its symbols in file and symboles in web

Comment: database was good en utf8

Comment: just that file functions.php was ansi , which correcpted my other file and become symboled